# convert curl to python3 and image to base64 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, base64

I have a curl command which is sending a jpg image converted to base64 to a web service:

```
curl -X POST --insecure \
https://link_to_the_web_service.com \
-H 'authorization:authorization_token'  \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{"model_spec": {"name": "inception", "signature_name": "predict_images"}, "inputs": {"images": {"dtype": 7, "tensor_shape": {"dim":[{"size": 1}]}, "string_val": ["IMAGE_CONVERTED_TO_BASE_64"]}}}'
```

I am converting the jpg image to base64 using the below website: "https://www.browserling.com/tools/image-to-base64". The execution of the curl command gives a success output.

Now I am testing the web service by taking jpg images, converting the curl command to python3 and the image to base64 using python3 like this:

```
import requests
import base64

host = 'https://link_to_the_web_service.com'
image = 'sample5.jpg'

image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(open('sample5.jpg',"rb").read())

headers = {'authorization': token, 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

data={"model_spec": {"name": "inception", "signature_name": "predict_images"}, "inputs": {"images": {"dtype": 7, "tensor_shape": {"dim":[{"size": 1}]}, "string_val": [str(image_64_encode)]}}}

request = requests.post(url=host, 
                    data=data,
                    headers=headers,
                    verify=False)

print(request)
```

and I receive a <500> response which means the web service is not able to read the image input.
I even tried 'base64.encodestring' to convert to base64 but no luck.

How do I properly convert the above curl command to python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` parameter of the `requests.post` method expects a string, not a dict. You should post your payload as JSON with the `json` parameter instead:

```
request = requests.post(url=host, 
                        json=data,
                        headers=headers,
                        verify=False)
```

Comment: I tried with json parameter. It is still <500> response.

Comment: I sent the file as a byte input instead of string input and it worked.